# Extend Blueprint class?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to override the `timestamps()` function found in the `Blueprint` class. How can I do that?

e.g.,

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps(); // <-- I want this to call my method instead of the one found in the base Blueprint class
    });
}
```

Comment: Why not extend the class?

Comment: @Simon_eQ: I'd be happy to, but I'm afraid `Schema::create` will still be passed a `Blueprint`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a new `blueprintResolver` function which takes a callback function which then returns the `Blueprint` instance.

So create your custom Blueprint class like this:

```
class CustomBlueprint extends Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint{

    public function timestamps() {
        //Your custom timestamp code. Any output is not shown on the console so don't expect anything
    }
}
```

And then call the `blueprintResolver` function where you return your `CustomBlueprint` instance.

```
public function up()
{
    $schema = DB::connection()->getSchemaBuilder();

    $schema->blueprintResolver(function($table, $callback) {
        return new CustomBlueprint($table, $callback);
    });

    $schema->create('users', function($table) {
        //Call your custom functions
    });
}
```

I'm not sure if creating a new schema instance with  `DB::connection()->getSchemaBuilder();` is state of the art but it works.

You could additionally override the `Schema` facade and add the custom blueprint by default.

Comment: This is great, and looks like a simple way to implement a similar change i wanted (adding a `bit()` method for MySQL). Maybe a bonehead question, but what file did you place/create your `CustomBlueprint` class in? i'm still new to Laravel (frameworks in general) so i want to learn best practices up front rather than throwing stuff all over. :) Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure whats the best option here either. I would suggest to create a new folder called `src` or `helpers` in the `app` directory and put your classes there. In my case I also create a similar folder structure like Laravel uses. So if I create my own `Blueprint` class I place it inside the folder `/app/src/MyApp/Database/Schema` and I also use the appropriate namespace.

Comment: Thanks Marcel. i'm struggling with this, as there seems to be a clear need to extend Blueprints & Grammars, but little documentation. i've also tried adapting this: http://goo.gl/vcTlEu to my needs, but get errors either in the route part (my namespace not found), or if i omit the route, i'm sending the wrong `Blueprint` type to `Builder`. Aggravating.

Comment: @cautionbug I think it would be better if you ask another question with your specific problem.

Comment: Is there a way to do this app-wide, so you don't have to set up your custom blueprint in each migration?

Comment: @JayK couple years late, but see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57539154/1376624)

Comment: where do I pass callback function?

Answer (score 7):

I likewise wanted to solve this in an "automagic" way, so took inspiration from @WesleySmith's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57539154/1064923) to implement a solution that involved overriding the base `Schema` facade that returns a customised `Blueprint` class.

However, as of Laravel 9, the `protected static function getFacadeAccessor()` method is now expected to return a string only, representing a lookup key in the service container. This change is documented in the [Laravel 9 upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade) (search for "getFacadeAccessor"), and [here's the relevant commit to the framework that made this alteration](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/8059b393eb45749d7e8840a41f33c99b2f4acafd). The upgrade guide has this to say:

> The getFacadeAccessor method must always return a container binding key. In previous releases of Laravel, this method could return an object instance; however, this behavior is no longer supported. If you have written your own facades, you should ensure that this method returns a container binding string.

For the `Schema` facade, this container binding key is the string `db.schema` (as seen [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8059b393eb45749d7e8840a41f33c99b2f4acafd/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L1307), although it hasn't been documented in the [Facade Class Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/facades#facade-class-reference) in the Laravel documentation yet).

Therefore my `Schema` class dispenses with the customised `getFacadeAccessor` method and relies on the parent class to return the `db.schema` key, and provides the logic for creating a custom schema builder using a static `customizedSchemaBuilder` method.

```php
class Schema extends BaseSchema
{
    /**
     * Get a schema builder instance for a connection.
     *
     * @param string|null $name
     *
     * @return Builder
     */
    public static function connection($name): Builder
    {
        return static::customizedSchemaBuilder($name);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves an instance of the schema `Builder` with a customized `Blueprint` class.
     *
     * @param string|null $name
     *
     * @return Builder
     */
    public static function customizedSchemaBuilder(string|null $name = null): Builder
    {
        /** @var Builder $builder */
        $builder = static::$app['db']->connection($name)->getSchemaBuilder();
        $builder->blueprintResolver(static fn($table, $callback) => new CustomBlueprint($table, $callback));
        return $builder;
    }
}
```

The logic to resolve the customised Builder that was previously in `getFacadeAccessor` should instead be included in your `AppServiceProvider`'s `register` method:

```php
/**
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('db.schema', fn() => Schema::customizedSchemaBuilder());
}
```

You should now be able to use your customised `Schema` facade and `Blueprint` classes in your migrations using Laravel 9.

Answer (score 6):

Marcel Gwerder's answer was a life saver. Like some of the users commented there, I wondered if this could be done more automagically. My goal was similarly to overwrite the `timestamps` method. After some tinkering, this is what I ended up with which is working for me:

I created a file at `app/Classes/Database/Blueprint.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Classes\Database;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint as BaseBlueprint;

class Blueprint extends BaseBlueprint
{
    /**
     * Add automatic creation and update timestamps to the table.
     *
     * @param  int  $precision
     */
    public function timestamps($precision = 0): void
    {
        $this->timestamp('created_at', $precision)->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
        $this->timestamp('updated_at', $precision)->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    }
}
```

I created a file at `app/Facades/Schema.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Facades;

use App\Classes\Database\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema as BaseSchema;

class Schema extends BaseSchema
{
    /**
     * Get a schema builder instance for a connection.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $name
     * @return Builder
     */
    public static function connection($name): Builder
    {
        /** @var \Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder $builder */
        $builder = static::$app['db']->connection($name)->getSchemaBuilder();
        $builder->blueprintResolver(static function($table, $callback) {
            return new Blueprint($table, $callback);
        });
        return $builder;
    }

    /**
     * Get a schema builder instance for the default connection.
     *
     * @return Builder
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor(): Builder
    {
        /** @var \Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder $builder */
        $builder = static::$app['db']->connection()->getSchemaBuilder();
        $builder->blueprintResolver(static function($table, $callback) {
            return new Blueprint($table, $callback);
        });
        return $builder;
    }
}
```

Inside `config/app.php` I updated the alias for Schema as follows:

```
'aliases' => [
    'Schema' => App\Facades\Schema::class,
],
```

Now, in my migrations, like the below, when I call `timestamps()`, it calls my overwritten method.

```
<?php

use App\Classes\Database\Blueprint;
use \Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class TimestampTest extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Throwable
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::connection('mysql')->create('some_table', static function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('some_column')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

    }

    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a few points to Marcel Gwerder's answer (which is already great):

- You can shorten `DB::connection()->getSchemaBuilder()` to `DB::getSchemaBuilder()` because Laravel automagically forward the method call to the connection instance.
- Each call to the `Schema` Facade already creates a new `Schema\Builder` instance, as can be seen in the `getFacadeAccessor()` method in the following files:

  - [Support/Facades/Schema.php - Laravel 4.2](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Schema.php)
  - [Support/Facades/Schema.php - Laravel 5.0-dev](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Schema.php)

(edit 2016-03-06)
A GitHub issue has been recently opened about this: [#12539](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12539).