# Extending Blueprint for SQLite in Laravel 5

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel-5

I have a custom `Blueprint` class, In order to use it I followed the steps in [this gist.](https://gist.github.com/Kindari/9283167)

Basically, it says I need to extend a `MySqlConnection` and use a `MySqlBuilder` that Laravel conviniently has in the **Schema** folder.

It worked great for MySQL! The problem is I'm using SQLite for testing, and I need the Bluepint there too, the issue is there is no base `SqliteConnection` nor `SqliteBuilder`...

Of course, I get the following Exception:

```
Argument 1 passed to CreateUsersTable::{closure}() 
must be an instance of MyBlueprint
instance of Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint given
```

Do I have to write those missing classes myself? Hope not

---

By the way, this question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444685/extend-blueprint-class) for Laravel 4 but I don't want to bind my Blueprint by hand on every migration...

Comment: halp pls internatz :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alrighty, my statement about `SQLiteConnection` missing was wrong, **it does exists** and apparantly there's no need for a `SQLiteBuilder` so `MySqlBuilder` must be a special exception.

I extended the SQLiteConnection as follows:

```
use Illuminate\Database\SQLiteConnection as ParentSQLiteConnection;

class SQLiteConnection extends ParentSQLiteConnection {
    public function getSchemaBuilder() {
        $builder = parent::getSchemaBuilder();
        
        $builder->blueprintResolver(function($table, $callback){
            return new MyBlueprint($table, $callback);
        });
        
        return $builder;
    }
}
```

And then in the service registration:

```
class MyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function register() {
        $this->app->bind('db.connection.sqlite', 'SQLiteConnection');
    }
}
```

I ommited some parts for brevity, mainly namespaces and where to place the service, but all of that can be deduced or looked up from the gist posted on my question as an example.

Hope this help lost souls find their way in the future.

Comment: Sorry, I switched to Java/Scala since 2015

Comment: Good luck to you :D

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to rewrite those classes, you just need to extend Blueprint. Your CreateUsersTable method is also expecting MyBlueprint and getting an instance of Blueprint.

You will need to also extend and rewrite the Schema facade or, just substitute it with your own service provider & binding that extends the default laravel class returned by "Schema"..

E.g
see: vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema.php
Create your own, you will need to replace the getFacadeAccessor to return your version of the object it currently returns. Your version should extend the current version to save on writing every method.

Your version will also need overriden versions of the create etc so that instead of returning Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint it returns an instance of MyBlueprint... MyBlueprint will extend Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint so that you can inherit all of its functionality, and you will then override the methods that should be different.

Now in your app/config/app.php switch out the line:

```
'Schema'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema',
```

And instead point the Schema facade to your version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; Unfortunately your approach works for Laravel 4 (I used it back then) but yields no result in Laravel 5. The way to extend Blueprint in L5 is following the gist at the beggining of my answer, but poses the problems stated afterwards.