# Extending Laravel 5.5/5.6 Blueprint

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, blueprint, package-development

How to extend **Laravel 5.5/5.6 MySQL Blueprint** with custom method **$table->myMethod()** like pre-built method **$table->timestamps();**?

I have tried an example with SQLlite: [Extending Blueprint for SQLite in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701195/extending-blueprint-for-sqlite-in-laravel-5#32721953)

But I couldn't get it work. I am developing my own package (using package development best practices) and would like include the Blueprint extension from there.

My devloped package has Laravel extension folder "Extension": 
**./packages/vendorname/packagename/src/Extension/**

There are files:

1) **./packages/vendorname/packagename/src/Extension/Blueprint.php**

```php
<?php

namespace Vendorname\Packagename\Extension;

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint as ParentBlueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Blueprint extends ParentBlueprint
{

     public function myMethod()
     {
          $this->text('custom_column')->default('Some value');
          $this->text('custom_column2')->default('Some value2');
     }
}
```

2) **./packages/vendorname/packagename/src/Extension/MySqlConnection.php**

```php
<?php

namespace Vendorname\Packagename\Extension;

use Vendorname\Packagename\Extension\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection as ParentMySqlConnection;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder;

class MySqlConnection extends ParentMySqlConnection
{

     public function getSchemaBuilder()
     {
          if (is_null($this->schemaGrammar)) {
               $this->useDefaultSchemaGrammar();
          }

          $builder = new MySqlBuilder($this);
          $builder->blueprintResolver(function ($table, $callback) {
               return new Blueprint($table, $callback);
          });

          return $builder;
     }
}
```

And my package has service provider:
**./packages/vendorname/packagename/src/VendornamePackagenameServiceProvider.php** with **register()** method:

```php
public function register()
{      if ($this->app->config->get('vendorname-packagename') === null) {
          $this->app->config->set('vendorname-packagename', require __DIR__.'/../config/vendorname-packagename');
     }

     $this->app->bind('db.connection.mysql', Vendorname\Packagename\Extension\MySqlConnection::class);
}
```

Also my package has migration file:
**./packages/vanilla/vanilla-admin/src/migrations/2018_02_07_213437_create_logs_table.php**:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
//use Vendorname\Packagename\Extension\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateLogsTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('logs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('package');
            $table->longText('log');
            $table->myMethod();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('logs');
    }
}
```

How can I use standard "use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;" in migration, beacuse I don't want to use "use Vendorname\Packagename\Extension\Blueprint;".

Also I got an error on running migration "php artisan migrate:refresh":

```php
Type error: Argument 1 passed to CreateLogsTable::{closure}() must be a
  n instance of Vanilla\VanillaAdmin\Extension\Blueprint, instance of Ill
  uminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint given, called in /Users/raido/.compos
  er/vendor/bin/laravel-packages/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/
  Database/Schema/Builder.php on line 164
```

Please help me find a solution. I searched over the internet and tested whole day, I couldn't get it work :(

Comment: use dc.connector.sqlite instead of db.connection.sqlite

Comment: Any update please , i get the same issue

Answer (score 5):

I found this when searching for the same question. I'm using Laravel 5.8 and do it this way.

1. Create custom Blueprint class

```
namespace App\Database\Schema;

class Blueprint extends \Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint
{
    public function datetimeCreatedAt($precision = 0)
    {
        return $this->dateTime('created_at', $precision);
    }

}
```

2. Create MySqlConnection class or what ever you need

```
namespace App\Database;

class MySqlConnection extends \Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection
{
    public function getSchemaBuilder()
    {
        $builder = parent::getSchemaBuilder();
        $builder->blueprintResolver(function ($table, $callback) {
            return new \App\Database\Schema\Blueprint($table, $callback);
        });

        return $builder;
    }
}
```

3. Change AppServiceProvider

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Database\MySqlConnection;
use Illuminate\Database\Connection;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        Connection::resolverFor('mysql', function ($connection, $database, $prefix, $config) {
            return new MySqlConnection($connection, $database, $prefix, $config);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer in 2019. Thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 2):

With Laravel 5.5, the best way to extend Blueprint is to register [macros](https://tighten.co/blog/the-magic-of-laravel-macros) in your `AppServiceProvider` boot method like so:

```
Blueprint::macro('yourmethod', function () {  
    // your method here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and I solved it by making a new **CustomBlueprint** class. I wrote a separate blog on this. Just go there and you find your answers.
Here I just give an example of migration file which have commonFields() method to add common fields in a model

```
    $schema = DB::connection()->getSchemaBuilder();

    $schema->blueprintResolver(function ($table, $callback) {
        return new CustomBlueprint($table, $callback);
    });

    $schema->create('roles', function (CustomBlueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->commonFields();
    });
```

I created CustomBlueprint class which have that method.

```
<?php
namespace App\common;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
class CustomBlueprint extends Blueprint
{
    public function commonFields()
    {
        $this->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();;
        $this->unsignedBigInteger('created_by')->nullable();
        $this->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();;
        $this->unsignedBigInteger('updated_by')->nullable();
        $this->timestamp('deleted_at')->nullable();;
        $this->unsignedBigInteger('deleted_by')->nullable();
        $this->boolean('is_deleted')->default(0);
    }
}
```

link : [custom-blueprint-in-laravel-mode](https://medium.com/@harshshah8996/custom-blueprint-in-laravel-model-a772997c2fa3)

Comment: I have to test that also ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this in migration:

```
public function up()
{
    $schema = \DB::getSchemaBuilder();

    $schema->blueprintResolver(function($table, $callback) {
        return new YourBlueprint($table, $callback);
    });

    $schema->create('table_name', function (YourBlueprint $table) {
    ...
```